# Checking if value exists in any of two columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas.

I am building a dataframe with `True` and `False` values using `.isin()` method.

There are 7 columns in my dataframe and I check if value exists in each column compared to the column on the left. It works out fine using `.isin()` method.

The problem is that I need to check if value exists in column A or column B to place a `True` or `False` value on my new dataframe column C.

For example:

df_1

```
A     B     C     D
1     a     1     a
a     b     a     
c     c     c     c
d     1           d
```

And I am checking if value `1` from column A exists in whole column B, C, D and where it does I pass a `True` statement to that row in that column where match was found.

And I am building new dataframe using masks:

```
mask_gclid_cloudflare_request_url = final_data.gclid.isin(final_data['Gclid from request url'])
mask_gclid_cloudflare_cookie = final_data.gclid.isin(final_data['Gclid from cookie'])

finalized_export.loc[~mask_gclid_cloudflare_request_url, ['Date from Cloudflare']] = ''
finalized_export.loc[~mask_gclid_cloudflare_cookie, ['Date from Cloudflare']] = ''
```

How would I check if for example value `1` from column C exists in either column `A` or column `B` using the `.isin()` method?

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If want boolean DataFrame in output simplier is compare by value without `isin`:

```
#if 1 is string use '1'
#df1 = df[['A','B']].eq('1')
df1 = df[['A','B']].eq(1)

df1 = (df[['A','B']] == 1)
```

With [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) only pas one element list with `1`:

```
df1 = df[['A','B']].isin([1])
```

---

```
print (df1)
       A      B
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False   True
```

For mask (Series) use one one 2 method [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one `True` per row:

```
print (df1.any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Or [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all Trues per row:

```
print (df1.all(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Would it work if I test one value agaisnt 2 columns like so ```df1 = df['A'].isin([['B','C']]```?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I think you are close `df2 = df[['B','C']].isin(df['A'])` - it means test if columns `B` and `C` contains any value of A

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Or `df3 = df[['B','C']].eq(df['A'], axis=0)` it means compare by rows - so first row of B, C with first A value, second row of B, C with second val of A...

Comment: Is testing `B` and `C` in column `A` the same as testing if `A` exists in columns `B` or `C`? I am going backwards in my dataframe and testing if values exists from right to left column wise. So I would want somehow to test if one columns value can be found in any of the next two. At the moment it feels like I am testing if those two columns contain value from the one column.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I think it is same `df[['B','C']].eq(df['A'], axis=0).any(axis=1)` with `df['B'].eq(df['A']) | df['C'].eq(df['A'])`

Comment: And using the second option from your last comment I do not need to pass the parameters as in your first example . -`axis=0).any(axis=1)`.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - yes, it was only solution if eed it in future ;)